# send post to insert a row in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

hello i started to learn php and js i trying to insert a row in wordpress database tablet, getting the info need to insert from another table but i having a problem with php file it not insert in the database here is the code i trying

```
<?php

/*
plugin name: test
description: local
author uri: local
*/
function set_items_list(){
}
?>

<div class="item" data-id="1">
<a href="#" class="item-preview">TEST</a>
</div>
<div class="item" data-id="2">
<a href="#" class="item-preview">TEST</a>
</div>
<div class="item" data-id="3">
<a href="#" class="item-preview">TEST</a>
</div>

<script>
     var itemnodes = document.getElementsByClassName('item-preview');
     var item = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
     
        for (var i = 0, size = itemnodes.length; i < size; i++) {
            itemnodes[i].addEventListener('click', function(i) {
            var id = item[i].getAttribute('data-id');
            console.log(id);
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("POST", "files/test.php", true); 
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            var response = this.responseText;
            console.log(response);
             }
        };
        
        var data = {id:id};
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));

         }.bind(null, i));
    }
    </script>
<?php

add_shortcode('list','set_items_list');
```

and the php file

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsondata = json_decode($contents, true);
    global $wpdb;


$wpdb->insert('add_items',array('FirstName'=> 'test1','SecondName'=> 'test2'));

echo $jsondata['id'];

exit;
?>
```

what i need is when press on a class="item-preview" it read the data-id from item and send it to php to insert the row in the database
everything is working right except php part at insert it showing in the console

Post
500
(anonymous) @ (index):34

Comment: You need to do more debugging. Is the issue JS, PHP, or HTML? Open the developer console and see if the AJAX request is sending.

Comment: There is a problem with `var data = {id:dataid};` as id is just an integer. dataid is undefined.

Comment: In your php script you want to echo something back to the ajax and also after the echo statement put an `exit;` otherwise the rest of the file will be sent back to your ajax.

Comment: thanks didn't saw this mistake ok now it sending

network -> name select test.php goto payload i found

{
  "id": "1"
}

at console 
console.log(response);
return empty

but it look like there no action happen in the php part i mean it didn't insert the row

it might be a problem in the php file it look like that now 

<?php
function test()
{
$id;
echo $id;

 global $wpdb;


$wpdb->insert('add_items',array('FirstName'=> 'test1','SecondName'=> 'test2'));
}
?>

maybe it wrong like that i not really sure

Comment: thanks for the info about exit;

Comment: ok i changed the php a little bit but now it always return echo "is is empty"

`<?php

  $id = $_POST['id'];
        echo "$id";
    if (empty($id)) 
        echo "is is empty";
    else
        echo "$id";
  exit;  
?>`

Comment: I always use PDO statements with PHP database stuff. Also I use SQLite because I think it is so much simpler than MySQL and it is also very fast and can handle quite large amounts of traffic (not as large as MySQL I believe).

Comment: ok i tried to use print_r($_POST); and it now showing Array
(
) in console

Comment: ok fixed by change the php to
`<?php

$contents = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsondata = json_decode($contents, true);

echo $jsondata['id'];

exit;
?>`

Comment: ok now having problem with the insert in db

user3422506 thanks for the info i will look at that but i think since wordpress database is using like that should use it like wordpress using it

Comment: I think you are correct that if you are using Wordpress you are probably best with MySQL. I still think PDO is good for PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but it might be the line `var data = {id:dataid};`

I think you want `var data = {"id": id}` instead.

Comment: thanks didn't saw this mistake ok now it sending

network -> name select test.php goto payload i found

{
  "id": "1"
}

at console 
console.log(response);
return empty

but it look like there no action happen in the php part i mean it didn't insert the row

<?php function test() { $id; echo $id; global $wpdb; $wpdb->insert('add_items',array('FirstName'=> 'test1','SecondName'=> 'test2')); } ?>

Comment: ok i changed the php a little bit but now it always return echo "is is empty"
`<?php

  $id = $_POST['id'];
        echo "$id";
    if (empty($id)) 
        echo "is is empty";
    else
        echo "$id";
  exit;  
?>`

Comment: ok i tried to use print_r($_POST); and it now showing Array
(
) in console

Comment: ok fixed by change the php to
`<?php

$contents = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsondata = json_decode($contents, true);

echo $jsondata['id'];

exit;
?>`